# How to read the projectId from webhook callback?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-webhooks

The **POST** `/webhooks/v1/systems/data/hooks` works fine, the events are created as expected, but the callback is missing the `project_id` for A360 that I need to access the file.

How to include that on the callback payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **hookAttribute** property on the POST body and include custom information, such as the projectId or any other information from your app. Here is an example:

```js
{
   "callbackUrl": "http://abcd1234.ngrok.io/forge/callback",
   "scope": {
      "folder": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.abcd1234"
   },
   "hookAttribute": {
      "projectId": "a.1234.abcd.5678.defg"
   }
}
```